# differential family of straigh line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with exercice:
**Find a differential equation whose solution is a family of straight line whose y intercept is a function of its slope.**

My concepts are:

$$y = ax + b$$
$$b = f(a)$$
I'm trying something to do with tangent function as a slope of straight line.
The correct answer of the exercise is: 
$$y = xy^{'} + f(y')$$
Could someone help me with solwing this problem?

I'll be very grateful

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they've started with

$$y = ax + f(a)$$

and then simply replaced $a = y'$ to make

$$y = y'x + f(y')$$

Conceptually at least it makes sense that this is consistent even though I'd have to check that there weren't additional solutions besides the straight line ones.